# Symfony, don't show the debug bar when the paged is served from the built in server

Tags: php, symfony, nginx, symfony-3.3, symfony3.x

I have a Symfony instance running on Linux with apache y NGINX. I'am starting the project using the built-in `server:start` command:

```
php bin/console server:start
```

Back to my browser, it loads me the Symfony start page but it also shows me the debug bar.

I have checked the `config_dev.yml` file and I think it is correct:

```
imports:
- { resource: config.yml }

framework:
    router:
        resource: '%kernel.project_dir%/app/config/routing_dev.yml'
        strict_requirements: true
        profiler: { only_exceptions: false }
web_profiler:
    toolbar: true
    intercept_redirects: false
```

However, if I try to access another route that I don't have, the debug bar is also shown:

[image: route not found]

Comment: Please use english it's a standard on StackOverflow.com or go to es.stackoverflow.com

Comment: I don't speak spanish but looking at the image it seems like a routing issue. Could you write your question in English por favor ?

Comment: Translated from es to en.

Comment: Please also update the question title to English.

Comment: @PeterDavidCarter yeah, right I forgot. Fixed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the prod env with:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/app.php

And accessing http://127.0.0.1:8000/app.php/a will give you an error page without the debug bar.

It is designed like this because the Symfony built-in web server is only meant to be used in development not in production. So the default environment is the "dev" one.